# What methods are there to obtain flourescence?

Tags: spectroscopy

Blackbody radiation is fairly easy to obtain. However, Atomic Emission spectrum based on  fluorescence requires more work and provides more information. Traditional methods use a flame or plasma to excite the atoms. I am interested in non-traditional methods of obtaining emission spectrum. For example a ruby laser allows for a (distorted) emission spectrum related to chromium.

How many different methods are there to obtain flourescent emission spectrums? (and what are they)

Answer (score 0):

One powerful method is LIF, [laser induced fluorescence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laser-induced_fluorescence).

You start with molecules or atoms in the ground state normally and use a laser with variable wavelength to excite them.

Whenever you hit a transition to an excited state that fluoresces laser light is absorbed and then the excited states emit light *in all directions*.

A simple photomultiplier detector can pick up the fluorescence, which is a great advantage as you do not need to disperse the fluoresence with a spectrometer - although you can disperse the fluorescence if you want to. If you deisperse the fluoresence then you obtain a fluorescence spectrum from individual excited state formed in the original laser excitation from the ground state.